sorting a list of tuples using lambda, python
I have a list of tuples that contains (name, score).
I want to sort the list on the second element (reverse = True) and if two names are similar then sort it on first element but not using reverse.
I have problem with the second part of the task that i couldn't find any solution by myself and i couldn't find any solution by myself.
Thanks for considering my question.
Let's say this is the following list:
averages = [('Ryan',7), ('Brian',11), ('Aiden',11), ('Jack',7), ('Mia',20)]

I'm using lambda for it as below:
averages.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]),reverse=True)

#output:
[('Mia', 20), ('Brian', 11), ('Aiden', 11), ('Ryan', 7), ('Jack', 7)]

But the output that i want is:
[('Mia', 20), ('Aiden', 11), ('Brian', 11), ('Jack', 7), ('Ryan', 7),]


Try this:
averages.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))


Don't just post code, explain how it solves the problem.

@Barmar his code only misses a - probably just a typo. There's not much to explain. Only that -x[1] sorts the list in descending order by the second element of each tuple
